# how to send Post request from express.js to another server ( java)?

Tags: node.js, post, request

I have to send data (json object) to another webserver (java).

This is my node.js code

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var data = querystring.stringify({
        username: "myname",
        password: " pass"
    });

    var options = {
        host: 'www.javaserver.com',
        port: 8070,
        path: '/login',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("body: " + chunk);
        });
    });
    req.write(data);
    req.end();

});

app.listen(8090);
```

This is not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are repeating req, and res variables for the post request. I have updated your code and tested it working with requestb.in

```
var express = require('express');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var data = querystring.stringify({
    username: "myname",
    password: " pass"
  });

  var options = {
    host: 'requestb.in',
    port: 80,
    path: '/nfue7rnf',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
  };

  var httpreq = http.request(options, function (response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      res.send('ok');
    })
  });
  httpreq.write(data);
  httpreq.end();
});

app.listen(8090);
```

Please update the request host and path in the code to the values you need. Let me know if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: thanks lot for your reply ....i have tried this one node.js server to another node.js server ,this is sending request but i am not able to get data....how to get ? req.query is coming like empty

Comment: Use `req.body` to fetch the data on the other server.

Comment: i am sending json object as a data so here should i change content type?  what should i do if it is ?

Comment: Set it to `application/json`, you may not require to stringify the post data. Also, if possible make use of `request` module, it is more convenient that using `http.request`.

Answer (score 2):

Please list exact error, "this is not working..." is not very helpful to identify the issue. The code is moreover fine with minor issues.

```
var http = require("http");
var querystring = require("querystring");
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    var data = querystring.stringify({
        username: "myname",
        password: " pass"
    });

    var options = {
        host: 'www.javaserver.com',
        port: 8070,
        path: '/login',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res)
    {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("body: " + chunk);
        });
    });
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
});
app.listen(8090);
```

The only thing to care about is, there should be a server at www.javaserver.com:8070 to give response for /login for data being POST'ed in this case the login credentials.