# send request to other server from express node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, request

So I am trying to send a request from express node.js to another URI :

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    http.get(URI, function(response) {
        console.log("Got response: " + response.statusCode);
        res.send(response);
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
});
```

This sends back an error message as follows :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/login (anonymous function) @ 
loginButton.js:48getSync @ loginButton.js:34(anonymous function) @ 
loginButton.js:22
loginButton.js:25 DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 
'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:3000/login'.
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/index/loginButton.js:48:13
at getSync 
(http://localhost:3000/javascripts/index/loginButton.js:34:12)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> 
(http://localhost:3000/javascripts/index/loginButton.js:22:13)
```

I've tried to update it to the suggestion from :
[how to send Post request from node.js to another server ( java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526757/how-to-send-post-request-from-node-js-to-another-server-java?rq=1)
but the same error message is thrown. Does anyone know what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

With `http.get`, the `response` is a stream.  As such, you either need to build up the entire body of the object (concatenate chunks from the stream) or you need to use a method that streams.

In express, `res.send` will send the data and close the connection.  It assumes you have sent the entire payload.

Instead of using `.send`, use `.write` which sends the incoming chunks right back out.

The adjusted code would look something like this:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    http.get(URI, function(response) {
        res.write(response);
    }).on('end', function() {
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: I made a dumb mistake in the code and left the `error` in place when it should have been `end`.  probably won't fix it, given the last...but thought I'd at least do the right thing here and get rid of the sloppy stuff I dumped here.

Comment: yup still same error. im wondering if it should be possible to make this sort of get request from within a client get request at all?

Comment: also, if I remove the .on('end', fun...) and put something like res.send('test') or res.render('test') this works, but res.send(response) throws the same error. rather confusing